# cur.executemany not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have the following function that is supposed to batch insert a list of IPv6 IPs

```
def insertToDb(ipList):
  print("OK")
  try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='mydb' user='myuser' host='hanno.db.elephantsql.com' password='mypass'")
  except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")
  cur = conn.cursor()
  try:
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO ip (ip) VALUES(%s)", ipList)
    conn.commit()
  except Exception as e: print(e)
  print("Inserted!")
```

I get the following message

> not all arguments converted during string formatting

What is the correct formatting needed?

Comment: ipList should be a list of tuples containing the value

Comment: I think I already have it as a list of tuples, here is how I create the list 
ipList = [] and then I add the IPs with ipList.append(address) in a loop, i then l  call insertToDb(ipList)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `executemany`, you may just need to convert `ipList` to a list of tuples like below :

```
params = [(ip,) for ip in iplist]
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO ip (ip) VALUES(%s)", params)
```

or you can also change the way you build the list to :

```
ipList.append((address,))
```